# 4.5 .Net Parse.dll 1.6.0 does not have a strong name?

Tags: .net, dll, parse-platform

I would to know if it is normal that the Parse.dll .net package (4.5), version 1.6.0 does not have a strong name, while the 1.5.0 had one.
I have a strong name error during compilation now that I have updated to 1.6.0.

Any idea? Shouldn't this dll be signed by Parse?

The twin lib Parse.NetFx45.dll has a strong name.

Comment: Yes, it is quite normal for a library author to forget to sign an assembly.  Just sign it yourself by building from source.

Comment: Uh ok... I will do that. Thought it was quite abnormal, but ok. Thanks :)